# Flip / mirror an image horizontally + vertically with css

Tags: html, css, transform, css-filters

Im trying to flip an image to display it 4 ways : original (no changes), flipped horizontally, flipped vertically, flipped horizontally + verticly.

To do this Im doing the below, it works fine apart from the flip horizontally + vertically, any idea why this wouldnt be working ?

Ive made a JS fiddle of the issue here : https://jsfiddle.net/7vg2tn83/

```
.img-hor {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

.img-vert {
        -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1);
        filter: FlipV;
        -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}

.img-hor-vert {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";

        -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1);
        filter: FlipV;
        -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try this:

```
.img-hor-vert {
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vg2tn83/1/

It wasn't working before because you were overriding the `transform` in your css. So instead of doing both, it just did the last one. Sort of like if you did `background-color` twice, it would override the first one.

Answer (score 31):

To perform a reflection you can use, the transform CSS property along with the rotate() CSS function in this format:

```
transform: rotateX() rotateY();
```

The function rotateX() will rotate an element along the x-axis and the function rotateY() will rotate an element along the y-axis. I find my approach intuitive in that one can visualize the rotation mentally. In your example, the solution using my approach would be:

```
.img-hor {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); // Rotate 180 degrees along the y-axis
}

.img-vert {
  transform: rotateX(180deg); // Rotate 180 degrees along the x-axis
}

.img-hor-vert {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg); // Rotate 180 degrees on both
}
```

The JS fiddle to demonstrate the solution is https://jsfiddle.net/n20196us/1/

Answer (score 17):

You may do a `transform: rotate(180deg);` for the horizontal+vertical flip.

Comment: This would only work on symmetrical images. Since you'd be rotating and not flipping the image. E.g.: take the letter (d). Rotating: d | p. Flipping: d | b.

Comment: @warkentien2 Flip it horizontal+vertical as asked by OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply only a single transform rule for any selector.
Use

```
.img-hor-vert {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    filter: FlipH FlipV;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH FlipV";
}
```

I am unsure which IE will accept multiple filters though.

Answer (score 2):

Flip image horizontally and vertically with TailWindCSS you can use this.

```
/* Flip horizontally */
<img src="..." alt="..." class="transform -scale-x-100">

/* Flip vertically */
<img src="..." alt="..." class="transform -scale-y-100">
```

Answer (score 2):

This classes works on image tag too.

```css
.box {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flipH {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

.flipV {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: FlipV;
    -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}
```

```html
<span class="box">
  Original
  <br />
  \(*.^)c
</span>

<hr />

<span class="box flipH">
  Flip H
  <br />
  \(*.^)c
</span>

<span class="box flipV">
  Flip V
  <br />
  \(*.^)c
</span>
```