# <a-sky> only display image with side:back

Tags: aframe

My sky image will display with material side:back but not with side:front... I'm mystified. Currently showing with side:back here:
https://dour-blouse.glitch.me/

The image is reversed, and I don't want it to be. If side:back is correct, should I just flip the image in photoshop?

Comment: I'm going to photoshop the image to reverse it, but if there is a a-frame way to do this I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can flip the image using the `scale` attribute (setting the scale to -1 inverts the image in either axis) , and then switch the visible side:

```
scale="-1 1 1" material="shader: flat; side: front;  src:#nyc"
```

Comment: also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32875781/2425787) anwser on flipping images