# How can I flip an element 180degrees with CSS?

Tags: css, transform

I don't want to rotate it - it's not 1998!
Can I purely flip this element when the is-expanded class is added?

```
 .resources__icon {
            @include icon('arrow-down-white', 28, 18);
        }


    .is-expanded.resources__icon {
                 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
                 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
                 -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
                 transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flip / mirror an image horizontally + vertically with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875695/flip-mirror-an-image-horizontally-vertically-with-css)

Comment: Unless you need to support very old browsers and IE, it hasn't been necessary to use vendor prefixes for those in many years.

Answer (score 2):

ScaleY can flip an image, not just "change the scale" - use scaleY instead of rotate

```
.resources__icon {
            @include icon('arrow-down-white', 28, 18);
        }


    .is-expanded.resources__icon {
                    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
                    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
                    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
                    transform: scaleY(-1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it: Replace translate to rotate please!

```css
.rotate{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
1. None rotate
<br>
<img src="http://hocwebchuan.com/reference/tag/images/img_sakura.jpg" width="100">
<br>
2. Rotate
<br>
<img class="rotate" src="http://hocwebchuan.com/reference/tag/images/img_sakura.jpg" width="100">
```