# Horizontal image flip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to flip the image Horizontally when press the button.

I wrote a function that triggers every time the button is pressed.

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="image-root"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
          width: this.state.size + 'px',
          height: this.state.size + 'px'
        }}
        >
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}><FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="arrows-alt-h" title="flip"/></button>
          <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="clone" title="clone"/>
          <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="expand" title="expand"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to flip the image?

Comment: And what actually happens? (Nothing / something weird?)

Comment: One workaround would be using the js on the button to add a class, and proceed as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875695/flip-mirror-an-image-horizontally-vertically-with-css

Comment: I have a grid of pictures and each one has 3 button, one of them is to flip it horizontally I managed to flip all of them, in the .sass file I used -> with transform: scaleX(1), but in the .js file I can't understand how to do it when pressing a button on specified picture

Comment: so add css to flip it.... Add a single class name and css rule to flip.

Comment: Add the required css to a class, and add that class to the required image on button click

Comment: ok I added a css file in order to flip the image with the code

.img-hor {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

I imorted the file to the image class, the background of the image class is loaded from flicker gallery, how can I flip it now?

sorry for the newbe questions, I have 24hr react and JS experience in total -(

Answer (score 0):

First add the required code to a CSS class as follows, but don't add this class to any HTML element yet, because it should be added only when the button is clicked

**CSS**

```
.img-hor {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Let `img1` be the id of the image you want to flip, now we want to add this extra class to that is order to flip it. To do so, we add this js to the button as required

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("img1").classList.toggle("img-hor");
```

Codepen example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rXNgVQ